# SSH Tunnel - Performant alternatives for exposing a local port to remote machines?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, ssh, tunneling

I have Server A running at home in a Carrier-Grade NAT environment. Due to this I cannot open a port directly in my router. I also have Server B on a cloud hosting provider, which has a static public IP address that can have ports opened to. Both machines run Ubuntu linux.

So far the best solution for me was SSH Tunneling, but it comes with a performance drawback known as TCP-over-TCP.

I have tried several solutions and each one of them had some problems:

1. OpenVPN/Wireguard: I do not want to route Server A's **entire** traffic to a remote server, only expose a few ports (while keeping them accessible from the LAN, too)
2. ngrok: Centralised service, has several limitations (like max connections, etc)
3. LocalTunnel: HTTP(S) only. I want to forward TCP traffic.
4. SSH Tunnel: discussed above
5. Most other solutions: Centralised (non-selfhostable) or HTTP(S) only

I also need the original IP address of the client accessing the port through Server B to be visible to Server A. What software should I try?

Comment: What about ssh forwarding instead? Then there is no TCP being tunneled.

Comment: @HåkanLindqvist isn't that the same as SSH Tunneling?

Comment: No, tunneling is more of a VPN-like thing where you get a tun-device that you can tunnel actual connections over. Forwarding creates a listener on one end that forwards traffic to the other end where a connection is made to the specified endpoint (by ssh/sshd respectively).

Comment: @HåkanLindqvist I think there is a misunderstanding. I cannot open any port on Server A because its on a NAT. I can only open ports on Server B. I want users connecting to a port on Server B's public IP address, lets say the port is 5000 to actually get the for example website or a game server streamed from Server A. I need a reverse connection from Server A to Server B to do that, right?

Comment: Ssh has options for forwarding in both directions (see `-R` as well as `-L` in the `ssh` options). I don't think your requirements rule out that as a possibility?

Comment: Perhaps you could use a VPN solution but without routing all the traffic? Maybe assigning a separate IP address for your service or using netfilter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the perfect tool - [frp](https://github.com/fatedier/frp).
Seems to do exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Implement IPv6. Put A in an external facing /64 net. Allow in firewall as desired.

Any IPv6 host on the internet can access A directly.

IPv4 is more complicated. It is possible to get client IP address via layer 7 tricks, HTTD Forwarded header, or the PROXY protocol. But you still would need some method to traverse the NAT from the proxy at B to the backend at A.